# How do spacecraft protect their engines from micrometeroids?

Tags: engine-design, failure, meteoroid

A meteoroid impact on an engine bell can easily rupture a coolant pipe. Or it can create an imperfection in the backing plate from where cracks can form. Or it can destroy an injector. All of these can be fatal.

Yet by design, the interior of an engine bell cannot have a micrometeoroid shield. So how do spacecraft such as the Shuttle, Soyuz, and other manned and unmanned spacecraft protect the interior faces of the engines, main or otherwise?

It does seem to be that the Shuttle pointed the main engines at Earth, and the Soyuz has a lid. Are these protective measures?

Comment: You're wrong about the shuttle. They were more concerned about the TPS than the main engines. At the end of the program, when not docked or using a different attitude for some specific reason, shuttle mostly flew in -ZLV -XVV attitude, which means  the -X axis (out of the tail) was pointed in the direction of motion, to protect the nose cap.  You can see the attitude callouts in the flight plan here nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/567071main_FLT_PLN_135_F.pdf and the axes are defined: https://web.archive.org/web/20111026205414/www-lite.larc.nasa.gov/level1doc/bacs.html

Comment: The main engines did not deorbit the Shuttle.

Comment: @RonJohn the OMS did. And the OMS would have the same problems

Comment: @Abdullah the OMS never failed.  *Ipso facto*, they didn't have the same problems.

Comment: In the question it is assumed that spacecraft protect their engines from micrometeorites, but is this really the case? I haven't ever seen an engine-protection system...

Comment: Maybe this should be completely different question - is it possible for a micrometeoroid to come from behind while an engine is firing, and make it all the way to the back to impact the top of the combustion chamber?

Comment: @Steve it doesn't matter whether it's firing or not if it *will* from re before repairs are conducted, which is usually true.

Comment: Are engines even notably vulnerable to micrometeoroids, or more vulnerable from the inside than from the outside?

Comment: @ikrase yes. The coolant jacket probably has much thinner walls than the backing plate.

Comment: @Abdullah IIRC the shuttle OMS bells were just metal with an antirust coating. Only the chamber way down inside was actually cooled, so only a precise hit would go down the thermal exhaust port and potentially cause damage to the functional bits